# JQuery to Javascript function Scroll

Tags: javascript

I have JQuery code, can somebody tell me how to write it in JavaScript? I have a project without using JQuery.

Maybe a silly question but I can not help myself

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var boxMargin = 15;
        var boxLeft = $("#box").position().left;            
        var containerHeight = $("#box").closest("#content").height();
        var containerOffset = $("#box").closest("#content").offset().top;
        var height = $("#box").outerHeight();

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            $("#box").each(function() {
                var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                if (windowScroll < containerOffset) {
                    $(this).removeClass("fixed bottom");
                } else if (windowScroll > containerHeight + containerOffset - height - 2*boxMargin) {
                    $(this).removeClass("fixed").addClass("bottom").css({"left": ""});
                } else {
                    var leftValue = boxLeft + $(this).closest("#content").offset().left;
                    $(this).removeClass("bottom").addClass("fixed").css({"left": leftValue});
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: jquery is javasacript...

Comment: Ziomell meant pure javascript (no frameworks / libraries)

Comment: Okey I know, but I need to do this without using the jquery library

Comment: May you edit the title? "jQuery to Java" is wrong.

Comment: Also, asking for code translation is off-topic. Please be more specific with your issue.

Comment: Read the JQuery Docs for each function and compare the description with the JavaScript functions described @ MDN.  The internet will help  :)

Comment: I have a script http://jsfiddle.net/xHQyK/ It needs a functional system

Comment: @Ziomell I dunno why you use an `each` on a QS that targets an ID

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt :

```
function offTop(elem){
  /*from https://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html, I added some handy stuff to the return statement*/
  var curleft = curtop = 0;
  if(obj.offsetParent){
    do{
      curleft+=obj.offsetLeft;
      curtop+=obj.offsetTop;
    }while(obj=obj.offsetParent);
    return {"top": curtop, "left": curleft};
  }
}
```

```
window.attachEvent("onload", function(){
  var boxMargin = 15;
  var boxLeft = document.querySelector("#box").scrollLeft;
  var containerHeight = document.querySelector("#content").scrollHeight;
  var containerOffset = offTop( document.querySelector("#content") ).top;
  var height = document.querySelector("#box").offsetHeight;

  window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
    for(var el of document.querySelectorAll("#box")){
      var windowScroll = window.pageYOffset;/*maybe sthng better here ?*/
      if(windowScroll < containerOffset){
        el.classList.remove("fixed");
        el.classList.remove("bottom");
      }else if(windowScroll > containerHeight+containerOffset-height-(2*boxMargin)){
        el.classList.remove("fixed");
        el.classList.add("bottom");
        el.style.left=undefined;/*i dunno if empty string is enough here, so i put undefined instead*/
      }else{
        var leftValue = boxLeft + offTop( document.querySelector("#content") ).left;
        el.classList.remove("bottom");
        el.classList.add("fixed");
        el.style.left = ""+leftValue+"px";
      }
    }
  });
});
```